# Why does formatting a time with AM/PM specifier return null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, format

I have a query where a formatted expression is returning null:

```
declare @FormatString nvarchar(max) = N'hh:mm tt'
select M_STARTTIME as [Memo Time 1]
    , convert(time,M_STARTTIME) as [Memo Time 2]
    , format(convert(time,M_STARTTIME), @FormatString) as [Formatted Memo Time]
    , convert(time, getdate()) as [Current Time]
    , format(getdate(), @FormatString) as [Formatted Cur Time]
from MEMO
where M_STARTTIME is not null
```

*M_STARTTIME* holds an *nvarchar* field with values such as '10:27', '13:01', '8:25' and null. In this query:

1. [Memo Time 1] displays the string field
2. [Memo Time 2] displays the memo time as a time field correctly
3. [Formatted memo time] returns a null - for all rows
4. [Current Time] shows the current time
5. [Formatted Cur Time] shows the current time formatted using the format specifier.

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx), `FORMAT` returns null for errors other than a culture that is not valid. For example, null is returned if the value specified in format is not valid. I have not been able to identify where the error is though (I'm assuming i've missed something really obvious, or the issue is something really subtle).

Converting the *nvarchar* to a time should not be the problem, the time displays correctly in column 2. Formatting using the time specifier should not be the problem, since I use the same time specifier on another time value.

Interestingly, according to example D in the MSDN link (time values) that time format specifier should cause an error because the ':' is not escaped. If that is the case why is *[Formatted Cur Time]* working? Also, if I escape the format specifier with:

```
declare @FormatString nvarchar(max) = N'hh\:mm tt'
```

then the [Formatted Memo Time] still returns null and the *[Formatted Cur Time]* still returns the current time.

dbcc checktable (MEMO)

...identified no issues

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: tt is a valid format specifier for datetime, but not time. The \ is also optional in datetime, but not time. Example at end.

I think the tt is the problem
I am not finding tt for time formatting - what is it supposed to do?

Did you try without using @FormatString?
Below works

```
declare @FormatString nvarchar(200) = N'hh\:mm'
declare @TimeChar nvarchar(200) = N'10:27'
select @FormatString
select @TimeChar
select convert(time, @TimeChar)
select format(convert(time, @TimeChar), N'hh\:mm')
select format(convert(time, @TimeChar), @FormatString)
```

Example:

```
select format(convert(time    , '10:27'), N'hh\:mm')   -- returns 10:27
     , format(convert(time    , '10:27'), N'hh:mm')    -- returns NULL (need to escape ':'):
     , format(convert(time    , '10:27'), N'hh:mm tt') -- returns NULL
     , format(convert(datetime, '10:27'), N'hh:mm tt') -- returns 10:27
```

Comment: Yes, i tried without @FormatString - my original version was just a string literal. I moved to a variable to ensure I was using exactly the same format specifier and I wasn't missing a simple typo while tired.

Comment: It turns out you are right. the tt format specifier (AM/PM) is valid for the datetime datatype but not the time datatype. I'm shaking my head at that one.

Comment: I've edited your answer to clarify and added an example.

Answer (score 1):

tt is the indicator for AM/PM

Paparazzi, I replaced your last two lines as follows:

```
select format(convert(datetime, @TimeChar), N'hh:mm tt')
select format(convert(datetime, @TimeChar), @FormatString)
```

This returns 10:27 AM

Comment: tt is only valid for datetime - but maybe that works for the OP

Comment: it works when formatting getdate(), it doesn't work when formatting convert(time, m_starttime). That's what annoys me most - if it worked for both, or failed for both it would make a kind of sense. What is the difference between GetDate() and convert(time, m_starttime) that is causing a null?

Comment: GETDATE() returns a datetime result.  The code that worked for me changed your original "time" type to a "datetime".  It appears that you will need to use datetime in order to obtain the AM/PM designation.

Answer (score 1):

> [Formatted memo time] returns a null - for all rows

The behavior is descried [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/48176.format-function-behavior-difference-datetime-vs-time-datatypes.aspx). TL;DR:

SQL Server datatype `time` is mapped to .NET datatype `TimeSpan`; so the rules for [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) ***TimeStamp*** format specifiers apply. More TL;DR:

- `t` and `tt` is not supported
- separator symbols `.` and `:` must be escaped using `\`